# WSL update "Element Not Found"

Tags: windows-11, wsl2

When running `wsl --update` on my **windows 11** machine, it errors at 90% with **"Element not found."**.

I can't find anything online about this related to windows 11, only errors for windows 10.
There isn't an error code, and I'm not sure if there are any logs to help (that I know of).

`wsl --status` shows I have a `Kernel version: 5.10.16`. I am using **wsl2**.

I've tried:

- `wsl --update --web-download`
- unregistering all distros.
- restarting my machine at different times.

Comment: `wsl --status shows I have a Kernel version: 5.10.16` ... interesting ...  `wsl --status` shows nothing like that on any Windows 10 or 11 machines I have

Comment: I was able to find possible solutions [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/3785) and [here](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/5631) both solutions are connected to the virtual hyper-V switches. Verify you have the current version of WSL from the Windows Store instead of installing the legacy WSL through optional features

Comment: @Antzy21 - Try installing the 2.0.14 WSL update manually.

Comment: Suspect this is a duplicate of: https://superuser.com/questions/1820365/wsl2-ubuntu-20-04-6-lts-not-working-wslregisterdistribution-failed-with-error/1820374#1820374