# WSL2 Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS not working: WslRegisterDistribution failed with error: 0x80070490

Tags: windows, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl2

After a windows update, WSL2 stopped working with:

```
Installing, this may take a few minutes...
WslRegisterDistribution failed with error: 0x80070490
Error: 0x80070490 Element not found.

Press any key to continue...
```

And when I press, it just closes the window.

I have checked checked if doesn't have any corrupt files on the windows.

```
sfc /scannow 
Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /ScanHealth 
Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /CheckHealth 
Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth
```

And after a restart, it still continues. Anybody fixed this problem or know the solution?

Comment: Make sure you are running the current version of WSL from the Windows Store instead of the legacy version installed through optional Windows Feature. [Here](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/7946) suggests we need the WSL logs to diagnose this problem

Comment: @Ramhound I checked the microsoft store and there is only option to 'open' it doesnt say update like other apps

Comment: What about the thread? The log? Make sure your running 2.0.14

Comment: make sure you run *wsl.exe --update* and delete the following key: *HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\PackagedCom\ClassIndex{A9B7A1B9-0671-405C-95F1-E0612CB4CE7E}*

Comment: @Ramhound I think the logs are under /dev/kmsg which I cant reach due to WSL2 not starting. Is there a place I can check through windows?

Comment: No, Ubuntu isn’t starting WSL absolutely should be running, besides the logs are generated on the Windows side. Regardless make sure your running 2.0.14 if not install it manually. Verify the keys when deleted (which solved it for others) doesn’t work, but without the logs no further diagnostic can be done. You should be providing the logs to Microsoft not us, as this likely is a WSL issue, but it hasn’t be reproduced since so few people upload the logs they requested

Comment: @Ramhound what is the default location for logs in windows, do you know? I am searching but all I found are under ubuntu

Comment: [This](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/10782) suggests it’s a COM issue, solved by getting rid of the key, and resolved in 2.0.11 but 2.0.14 is the current stable version so install that instead

Comment: The first GitHub link has instructions….At the very least confirm the version of WSL you have installed and if deleting the key worked…

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150289/discussion-between-ramhound-and-jeredriq-demas).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue you describe was fixed in WSL 2.0.14 and was caused by a COM error. You will have to manually update to 2.0.14 and then delete the following registry key:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\PackagedCom\ClassIndex\{A9B7A1B9-0671-405C-95F1-E0612CB4CE7E}
```

You can find the installer for WSL 2.0.14, [here](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/releases/tag/2.0.14), while [this](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/10782) GitHub issue explains the reason for the error by Microsoft

Comment: This solved it thanks a lot! With wsl.exe --update